# Can't clean memory with delete[] in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

After uncommenting `delete[] array;` I'm getting this error
`CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer`

What do I have to do to correct this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char ch;
    char* array = new char[0];
    int array_index = 0;
    while(cin>>ch){
        if(ch != '!'){
            array[array_index++] = ch;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    //delete[ ] array;

}
```

Comment: `new char[0]`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do I have to do to correct this problem?

You have to allocate sufficient memory to store your characters.  Zero chars is not enough:

```
char* array = new char[0];
                      ^^^
```

My advice would be to use `std::string`.  It will take care of memory management for you.

Comment: @AshotNavasardyan there is a great example at the bottom of [this documentation page for `std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Note that this example is looking for the end of a line , but it is easily changed to look for a `'!'` instead.

Comment: @AshotNavasardyan Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) that teaches C++ standard library containers early on instead of teaching the hard and less useful things first.